# PHPWord UTF-8 Values

Tags: php, utf-8, phpword

I need to be able to produce an X amount of Word Documents so i'm using PHPWord and a certain template.

I finally worked the replace Values issue but i'm stuck at inserting UTF-8 strings in the doc.(Greek)

`echo mb_detect_encoding($date);` right before the insert shows `UTF-8`.

Now i found the function that replaces them and it contains this

```
if(!is_array($replace)) {
    $replace = utf8_encode($replace);
}
```

So i thought double encoding might mess it up. I removed that but then when i try to open the
doc i just produced it won't. Some kind of error with the XML.

Anyone knows how can i bypass this? Or with what encoding should i insert the values to Word ?

Comment: I can't find one question in this post.

Comment: Any ideas on how to solve this and replace the values in the docx with `UTF-8` strings?

Comment: Edit your post to clarify your question, and provide as much code as you think is necessary for someone who is reading your question, and has no idea about what you're trying to do, to understand exactly what you want to do and what you're having trouble with.